# вывести без повтора

Tags: php, mysql, sql

есть код рабочий но в нем при выборке всегда повторяется $content пробовал ставить group by но это не спасает так как выборка из соседней таблицы не происходит

```html
$result = $pdo->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT news.content, newsImg.id, newsImg.idNews, newsImg.img_Realtor, newsImg.filename, newsImg.imgRealtorSmall, newsImg.fileNameSmall
FROM news
LEFT JOIN newsImg
ON news.id=newsImg.idNews
ORDER BY newsImg.id DESC;');
$result->execute();
if($result->rowCount() > 0){
     
    while ($myrow = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $content = $myrow["content"];
    $idNews = $myrow["idNews"];
    $img_Realtor = $myrow["img_Realtor"];
    $filename = $myrow["filename"];
    $imgRealtorSmall = $myrow["imgRealtorSmall"];
    $fileNameSmall = $myrow["fileNameSmall"];

    $file = explode(',', $fileNameSmall);
   
          echo" <div class='col-md-12'>
                  <h5>".$content."</h5>";
                

           foreach ($file as $key) {
                echo
                  "<img src='".$imgRealtorSmall.$key."' style='width: 100px; height: 100px; margin-bottom: 10px;'></div><hr><br>";
       }
    }

  }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как то не совсем ясно, что вы хотите получить. Как должно получиться, что бы не повторялось? У вас в поле filename значения уникальные, поэтому content повторяется и вы видимо эти сущности используете дальше где то.

Comment: я хочу чтобы где content не повторялось, а вместо повтора было пусто

Comment: Контент повторяется для каждой картинки, связанной с этим контентом.

Comment: да, а я хочу  один контент и несколько изображений

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вашу задачу можно решить с помощью использования переменных в запросе SQL.
Для наглядности вот подготовка данных:

```
CREATE TABLE NewsImg (
  Id INT,
  NewsId INT,
  FileName VARCHAR(50)
);

CREATE TABLE News (
  Id INT,
  content VARCHAR(10024)
);

INSERT News SELECT 3, 'some third content';
INSERT News SELECT 4, '<3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3.';
INSERT News SELECT 5, '(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)';
INSERT NewsImg SELECT 1, 3, 'file1.jpg';
INSERT NewsImg SELECT 2, 3, 'file2.jpg';
INSERT NewsImg SELECT 3, 4, 'file3.jpg';
INSERT NewsImg SELECT 4, 4, 'file4.jpg';
INSERT NewsImg SELECT 5, 5, 'file5.jpg';
```

Ваш запрос в упрощённом виде:

```
SELECT N.content, I.*
FROM News N
  LEFT JOIN NewsImg I ON N.Id = I.NewsId
ORDER BY I.Id DESC
```

Его результат:

```
content, Id, NewsId, FileName
(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.), 5, 5, file5.jpg
<3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3., 4, 4, file4.jpg
<3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3., 3, 4, file3.jpg
some third content, 2, 3, file2.jpg
some third content, 1, 3, file1.jpg
```

Запрос с использованием переменных:

```
SELECT 
  IF (RowType = 'First', content, null) content,
  Id, NewsId, FileName
FROM(
  SELECT N.content, I.*, 
    IF(@LastNewsId = I.NewsId, 'Not first', 'First')RowType, 
    @LastNewsId := I.NewsId
  FROM News N
    LEFT JOIN NewsImg I ON N.Id = I.NewsId
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @LastNewsId := NULL)L
  ORDER BY I.NewsId DESC, I.Id DESC
)T
```

Результат:

```
# content, Id, NewsId, FileName
(.)(.)(.)(.)(.)(.), 5, 5, file5.jpg
NULL              , 4, 4, file4.jpg
<3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3., 3, 4, file3.jpg
NULL              , 2, 3, file2.jpg
some third content, 1, 3, file1.jpg
```

Я не буду подробно расписывать как это работает. Можете прочесть на эту тему статью: [MySQL. Использование переменных в запросе](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_mysql_usage_of_query_variables.html)