# Как сделать такое в php

Tags: php, jquery

Здесь прячет повтор слов, в html они остаются , а надо что б полностью удалялись спасибо всем за помощь

```html
       var supervise = {};
  $('.col-md-12#book').each(function() {
  var txt = $(this).text();
  if (supervise[txt])
      $(this).remove();
  else
      supervise[txt] = true;
 });
```

Comment: А как вы в php собрались по ссылкам которые в html коде проходиться? Если только забирать контент через file_get_contents и потом по нём искать ссылки. Вас это устраивает? Тогда смогу описать как это сделать. Только всё равно не пойму что потом делать с этой HTML в которой через php удалить ссылки, опишите подробней проблему.

Comment: в этих ссылках идут повторяющиеся значения, вот думаю как убрать повторы вот до этого задавал вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/637936/вывести-без-повтора

Comment: Так вы с базы берете эти значения, покажите тогда код на php который создает эти ссылки

Comment: http://pastebin.com/bZirBySD

Comment: вот так код выглядет

Comment: <div class='col-md-12' id='book'>".$content."</a></div> Нашел только закрывающий тег ссылки, и переменная $content нигде не указана в коде, что-то недокопировали

Comment: переделал не много извините сейчас js  var supervise = {};
      $('.col-md-12#book').each(function() {
      var txt = $(this).text();
      if (supervise[txt])
          $(this).remove();
      else
          supervise[txt] = true;
     });

Comment: от куда переменная $content берет данные? в коде она не объявлена

Comment: $result->bindColumn(1, $content); c помощью pdo

Comment: помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Так `php` или жуквери.

Answer (score 0):

Введи дополнительный массив, добавляй в него все книги, а потом с его помощью проверяй уникальность новой книги.

```
$books = [];

while ($myrow = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
  $idNews = $myrow["idNews"];
  $img_Realtor = 'smallUploads/';
  $filename = $myrow["filename"];
  $imgRealtorSmall = $myrow["imgRealtorSmall"];
  $fileNameSmall = $myrow["fileNameSmall"];  

  if(array_search($content, $books) === false){
    $books[] = $content;
    echo "<div class='col-md-12' id='book'>".$content."</a></div><div class='col-md-2'><img      src='".$imgRealtorSmall.$fileNameSmall."' style='width: 100px; height: 100px; margin-bottom: 10px;'></div>";
  }
}
```

Обратите внимание чтобы в условии `if(array_search($content, $books) === false)` стоял знак строгого равенства `===`, а не `==`, так как функция `array_search` возвращает индекс элемента в массиве, и может вернуть 0.

И еще вот вот это `<div class='col-md-12' id='book'>` немного не правильно, я так понимаю таких блоков у вас много, а источники про атрибут `id` говорят:

> Идентификатор в коде документа должен быть в единственном экземпляре, иными словами, встречаться только один раз.

, поэтому лучше будет так `<div class='col-md-12 book'>`.